Error -36 when copying certain files from an old HDD to my macOS
I'm trying to copy some MKV files from an old HDD (exFat) to my macOS Sonoma (Version 14.1.2), but I'm getting error code -36. Most files can be copied without issue, but some are causing this error. The affected files can be played without issue on the old HDD and seem not to be corrupted. The error occurs after a significant part of a file has already been copied.
I've already tried using the 'dot_clean' command in the Terminal, as well as copying using the 'cp' command, but the problem persists. Subsequently, I tried duplicating the files on the old HDD itself, but this also failed with similar errors.
When using 'dot_clean', the metadata are captured from the parent folders and placed in the affected directories to avoid conflicts. These metadata might be missing or corrupted, leading to error messages like error code -36 when attempting to copy files between exFAT partitions.

Have you tried to play the file from start to end without skipping? Based on your description it is possible that the HDD has some bad sectors that belongs to the mentioned mkv file. Check the HDD for hardware defects and if it has some you can try ddrescue to copy the whole HDD image to a new drive.
